# Using Qt for only making a window to quickly render opengl inside of

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am interested with experimenting with Opengl on Windows 7.  My concern is that because Qt is more designed for applications that may have a complex GUI and other things that are not exactly game related, it is not suitable for high performance 3d graphics.

My intention is to use Qt ONLY for creating a window, than I will only use Opengl calls to create my graphics.  Using this method, will an Opengl program using a window created with Qt have very similar performance to a window created using the win32 api?  Should I just use SDL instead?  I only want a nice, easy, cross-platform way to create a window that I can "put my own opengl stuff" inside of.  I may also want to use it to receive keyboard and mouse events.

P.S. GLUT seems a little dated, so I wanted to use something new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem with using Qt for making a game isn't that Qt is generally for writing applications. That won't affect OpenGL at all. It's that Qt *isn't* designed for all of the other things you might need a game to do. Input, sound (not the kind of sound that Qt does), etc.

Your knowledge of tools that can be used to create OpenGL windows seems rather limited. You should investigate [some of the alternatives](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Related_toolkits_and_APIs#Context.2FWindow_Toolkits).

FreeGLUT is good for making demo applications. I would always suggest having this in your general set of tools, if for no other reason than to make proof-of-concept applications. When proving a graphical effect, it's best to do it in a limited, controlled environment first, and then transport it into your real application.

GLFW is good, as it also has facilities for input (joysticks, etc). But it, like FreeGLUT, has no way to get a HWND (or other kinds of platform-specific window objects), so manually attaching sound tools to them are a bit more difficult.

SDL, SFML, and Allegro 5 are all designed specifically for game-type applications. They offer a full range of input, sound, and other tools. Which one you choose to use is up to you, but these are most likely to be your best options.

Comment: Which one of those libraries, if any, has the best support for Opengl 4.2?

Comment: @JAKE6459: All of them and none of them. "Support" for 4.2 is not something that these libraries have to handle. They just provide an OpenGL context and manage the window; it's up to you to "support" 4.2 by loading the correct function pointers. There are [libraries for loading function pointers](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library), and most of those support 4.2.

Comment: OpenGL 4 isn't supported on some GPU at all, that's worth to be noticed. (popular Intel integrated GPUs, for example)